# can I encrypt and decrypt information on airtable?

Tags: airtable

Hi all hope you are well!

Is it possible to encrypt/decrypt data in Airtable? That is, take a text string eg 'foobar' from field A, apply encryption method to it and then place response - 'dslfgdg324kf3sd' in field B.  At some point in future assume I have the same key in another environment I can take the encrypted info - 'dslfgdg324kf3sd' and decrypt it back into the original value 'foobar.
Any suggestions most appreciated